# HOW TO SOLVE THIS IN DART?

Tags: dart, dart-null-safety

```
import "dart:math";
import "dart:io";

void main(){
  print("enter first number");
  double num1 = double.parse(stdin.readLineSync());
  print("enter second number");
  double num2 = double.parse((stdin.readLineSync());

  print (
    num1 + num2
        );
  
}
```

Why it doesnt compile

Enter two numbers from the user add them and the program returns their sum.

Comment: tell us what is the issue exactly?
What error messages you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

For `double.parse` it needs a `String`. But `stdin.readLineSync()` provides nullable String, means this method can return null or string. It is safe to use `.tryParse` and provide default String instead of using `!`.

```dart
double num1 = double.tryParse(stdin.readLineSync() ?? "") ?? 0;
print("enter second number");
double num2 = double.tryParse((stdin.readLineSync() ?? "")) ?? 0;

print(num1 + num2);
```

More about [`tryParse`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.2/dart-core/num/tryParse.html) and [understanding-null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues. First, `double.parse` requires a `String`, but `readLineSync` returns a `String?`. To solve, simply convert it by using the `!` operator, like

```
 double num1 = double.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!);
```

The second issue is that you have a `(` too many at the `num2 = double.parse((` part, so change

```
double num2 = double.parse((stdin.readLineSync());
```

to

```
double num2 = double.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!);
```